# Qt can't acces ui element created in designer

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I created a `QComboBox` in the Qt designer. Now I want to access that `QComboBox` in my `mainwidget`. But when the creator does not recognize `ui->comboboxName`. There is probably an easy solution but I can't seem to find one.

This is the `QCombobox` in my ui file, and I can't access rolKeuze in the header of the widget or in the source of the widget

```
<widget class="QComboBox" name="rolKeuze">
 <item>
  <property name="text">
   <string>Bouwmeester</string>
  </property>
 </item>
 <item>
  <property name="text">
   <string>Burgemeester</string>
  </property>
 </item>
</widget>
```

Comment: Please post your cpp and ui files.

Comment: We need more code. At least header and .cpp file wher you're trying to access rolKeuze

Comment: Clean all, run qmake manually and rebuild, it usually helps.

Answer (score 1):

First tell us the error you get.

Also check if *ui* member is an pointer to the ui generated code (it might be an object and you need `ui.comboboxName`) and sometimes the tools don't detect the modified .ui file and don't re-generate the c++ code for your new add widgets if that's the case use *run qmake* and than build your project.

Comment: yes ui is a member, and it is possible to acces other ui elements like labels i created via ui->labelname, runnning qmake didnt help :S

Comment: _rolKeuze_ seems to be the name of your QComboBox, so the code will be: ui->rolKeuze

Comment: undeclared variable rolKeuze :S

Comment: You can delete the generated files and force the uic to regenerate those (you might want to backup your project and also check the systems date/time and modified date/time for files - some inconsistency there might be the reason why the generated code is not updated when you use _run qmake_ from build menu)

Comment: I found the solution, apparantly ui->qcombobox name did work, it's just not updating the editor for some reason :d

Comment: @CédricVandelaer Then how did you solve it?

Answer (score -1):

In my older qt3 environment I forgot to add the include for the QT-combobox to the .cpp file using the ui-item. So even if the ui-file was included, the .cxx generated, the code was still unaware of the type "qcombobox". So the below include had to be added to the cpp-file

```
#include <qcombobox.h>
```

:)