# Qt can't acces ui element created in Qt designer

Tags: c++, qt, widget

I have a same problem as the one mentioned in this post:

[Qt can't acces ui element created in designer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17040035/qt-cant-acces-ui-element-created-in-designer)

I added a button which has a name "`config`" in **Qt Designer** onto a dialog (`DepthMapGenerationDialog`). Then I tried to access it through `ui->config` in file 'DepthMapGenerationDialog.cpp' but it gives me an error:

```
"class::Ui::DepthMapGenerationDialog has no member named 'config'".
```

Anyone knows what happens?

Comment: Please add a minimal example that reproduces your issue. Add the text of the .ui file and the text of the cpp file.

Comment: Did you check the ui_*.h file for this widget / dialog to see if your button was in it yet? Perhaps uic did not yet regenerate the header.

Comment: Yes, I checked .ui file it has the button there.

Comment: I don't mean the .ui file I mean the header generated for the .ui.

Comment: Yes, it is there.

Comment: Then I expect the only way you can get help is to provide a minimal example as I mentioned in my first comment.

Comment: I tried to create a minimal example by creating a dialog then add a button on it, the interesting thing is now I can access in the code. But for the existing dialogs which I created days before, I still cannot access the new added ui element.